# same method name but different class name

Tags: java

This is  a sample program

```
class abc {
    void show() {
        System.out.println("First Class");
    }
}

class def {
    void show() {
        System.out.println("Second Class");
    }
}

class demo {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        abc a1 = new abc();
        def a2 = new def();
        a1.show();
        a2.show();
    }
}
```

Now what I want to ask is there are two different classes but they have same method name and same parameter,
What is this concept called in JAVA?

Comment: Since neither extend each other, nor share a common interface, then there is no concept to be had.  They're plain ol' POJOs.

Comment: As an aside, it's Java, not JAVA - and even in demo code, it's a good idea to follow naming conventions, starting class names with capital letters etc.

Comment: I have two pets cat and dog. Both have same name! What concept is in that. It's purely user implementation of design. You do what suits your needs the best.

Comment: This is called conceptless concept :)

Comment: without any dependencies between the two class, there can't be any concept as such. These are just simple classes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> What is this concept called in JAVA?

This is not a concept , you have named the method same in two un-related classes .  If one of the class was sub class of another then depending on the method signature , it would have been [overriding](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/override.html) or [overloading](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methods.html).

You would have implemented run time polymorphism , if one of the class was a subclass of another :

```
 class abc {
  void show() {
    System.out.println("First Class");
  }
}

// def extends from abc
class def extends abc {
  // show() method was overridden here
  void show() {
    System.out.println("Second Class");
  }
}

class demo {
  public static void main(String args[]) {
    // Use the reference type abc, object of type abc
    abc a1 = new abc();
    // Use the reference type abc, object of type def
    abc a2 = new def();
    // invokes the show() method of abc as the object is of abc
    a1.show();
    // invokes the show() method of def as the object is of def
    a2.show();
  }
}
```

Comment: So for relating both classes I have to inherit the second class from first class, right?
And this is called method overriding.

Answer (score 2):

> Now what I want to ask is there are two different classes but they have same method name and same parameter, What is this concept called in Java?

There's no "concept" here - they're just unrelated methods. To relate them, the method would have to be declared in a superclass or an interface that both classes implemented. That would then allow the method to be called polymorphically, with the caller only being aware of the interface.

Comment: I suppose the concept here is namespace ;-)

Answer (score 1):

> Now what I want to ask is there are two different classes but they
>   have same method name and same parameter, What is this concept called
>   in JAVA?

This is no special OOPS or Java feature. Any independent(not connected through some hierarchy) classes can have same method signatures.

For your knowledge, Method in a child class with the same signature as of parent is called overridden method. That is a OOPS method overriding concept.

Another OOPS concept is method overloading, which is within a class having methods with same name but different input arguments.

Answer (score 0):

### It is not a concept in java

If a class inherits a method from its super class, then there is a chance to override the method provided that it is not marked final.
For example

```
 class Animal{

   public void move(){
      System.out.println("Animals can move");
   }
}

class Dog extends Animal{

   public void move(){
      System.out.println("Dogs can walk and run");
   }
}

public class TestDog{

   public static void main(String args[]){
      Animal a = new Animal(); // Animal reference and object
      Animal b = new Dog(); // Animal reference but Dog object

      a.move();// runs the method in Animal class

      b.move();//Runs the method in Dog class
   }
}
```

Overloading methods within a class can have the same name and they have different parameter lists

```
public class DataArtist {
    ...
    public void draw(String s) {
        ...
    }
    public void draw(int i) {
        ...
    }
    public void draw(double f) {
        ...
    }
    public void draw(int i, double f) {
        ...
    }
}
```

Reference links : http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methods.html

Answer (score -1):

If one of the class was sub class of another then , it would have been overridding or overloading.

Comment: ...but they're not.  If they *were* then it would be; but they're not.