# Can it be said "method overloading", where two diff classes with no relationship (extends) having same method name but different types of arguments?

Tags: java, overloading

I am aware of the fact that a Java method can be overloaded in same class or in a subclass.

But can I overload a Java static method in a non-subclass ?

I am little bit confused about the below code.

```
class A {   
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Inside main's (String[]) method");      
    }
}

class B {
    public static void main(int[] args) {  // [1, 2, 3]
        System.out.println("Inside main's (int[]) method");
    }
}

public class _2b_Overloading_Staticmethod_NonSubClass {
    // JVM's entry point
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        A.main(args);
        B.main(new int[]{1,2,3});
    }
}
```

Comment: Where is the overload?

Comment: What is confusing you in this code? It seems pretty clear to me. You do not even have inheritance in place, so what should be confusing? Different unrelated classes having methods with the same name, whats the issue?

Comment: @Zabuza You're confusing overload with override. Overloading static methods is possible.

Comment: @Zabuza what do you mean it is not possible to overload a static method?? Do you mean override?

Comment: @Tom you beat by a few seconds :)

Comment: @JoakimDanielson - It's two methods (Forget about the last method in 2b_Overloading_Staticmethod_NonSubClass), with same name and different definition. public static void main(String[] args) and public static void main(int[] args)

Comment: You may want to precise why you are confused by the code you are using as example. Is there something happening that you do not expect?

Comment: @Tom - As you said, overloading a static method is possible in Same class as well as in sub class using inheritance, but here in my case both methods are not in same class and there is no inheritance between class A and B. Can't I say it is method overloading, since both methods have same method but different method signature ?

Comment: @missing.hashcode "Can't I say it is method overloading, since both methods have same method but different method signature?" No you can't, because that is not overloading. There are three things necessary to qualify overloading: 1. same class or relation between classes, 2. same method name, 3. different parameters. Both implementations have nothing to do with each other.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I am aware of the fact that a Java method can be overloaded in same
>   class or in a subclass.

Correct. A method is considered to be overloaded when multiple functions within the same class share the same name but differ by their arguments.

```
public class A 
{

    public void foo(int param)
    {
    }

    public void foo(string param)
    {
    }
}
```

> But can I overload a Java static method in a non-subclass ?

Yes you can. A subclass is a class that inherits attributes from a parent class (also known as a superclass). There is no rule against method overloading if a class is a subclass, not a subclass or if the methods are static.

```
public class A 
{

    public static void foo(int param)
    {
    }

    public static void foo(string param)
    {
    }
}
```

However the above code in your question is not an example of method overloading, because the methods with the same name (main) are not contained within the same class/scope. They do however differ by their argument lists, but that is not really of any consequence.

Comment: Don't call it functions. Call it methods. Also, this is about Java, so you should follow the Java Naming Conventions: variable names and method names are always written in camelCase. So `Foo` should be `foo`.

Comment: @AdaRaider - Thank you, As you said static and non static methods can be overloaded in same class or in sub class using inheritance, but here the problem is class B is not a sub class of A (So, this B class is non sub class of A), but has same method name but different method signatures ? My Point is regarding a "non sub class"

Comment: Apologies but your comment does not make much sense to me. A non subclass that is not inherited from is just a class. I think what might be confusing you is the fact that these functions have the same name but different parameters, but that does not automatically mean you are method overloading. Because these functions are contained within different classes this is not method overloading. This is simply two classes which happen to both contain the main() method.

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17939305/same-method-name-but-different-class-name

Comment: @AdaRaider - Yes, You are right and I was confused if it is Method overloading (It's not method overloading if I have the same method name in two different classes.) I am very sorry for wasting your time on concept less concept :) Thank you so much everyone.

Comment: No worries, I am choosing to be on here, dw about it! Keep asking questions it's a great way to learn and have a good day

Comment: If my answer was helpful please accept or upvote, cheers

Comment: If you want to know how it is possible that two classes can have function names that are the same you can look at name resolution: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_resolution_(programming_languages)

Comment: Solved : I was confused if it was Method overloading (Its clear that It's not method overloading even if I have the same method name, with different parameters in two different class methods not connected through any hierarchy)

Answer (score 1):

In addition, some backup from the JLS, plus a bunch of examples.

## Overloading

From the [JLS § 8.4.9](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.9):

> If two methods of a class (whether both declared in the same class, or both inherited by a class, or one declared and one inherited) have the same name but signatures that are not override-equivalent, then the method name is said to be overloaded.

- This counts for static members…

  ```
  class Foo {
      static int someStaticMethod(String s) {
          return 0;
      }
      static int someStaticMethod(String s, boolean b) {
          return 0;
      }
  }
  ```
- …as well as non-static ones:

  ```
  class Foo {
      int someMethod(String s) {
          return 0;
      }

      // Method overloading
      int someMethod(String s, boolean b) {
          return 0;
      }
  }
  ```
- Overloading is also the case if a class inherits a method from another class:

  ```
  class Bar extends Foo {
      // This is also a case of overloading, because Bar inherits
      // someMethod(String) from Foo
      int someMethod(String s, double d, boolean b) {
          return 0;
      }
  }
  ```

#### But

**If both methods are unrelated, despite having the same name, they are never said to be overloaded**.

- This is the case for two non-static methods

  ```
  class Alpha {
      void anotherMethod(String s) { }
  }
  class Bravo {
      // No overloading involved
      void anotherMethod(boolean b) { }
  }
  ```
- as well as static methods:

  ```
  class Charlie {
      static void someThirdMethod(String s) { }
  }
  class Delta {
      // No overloading involved
      static void someThirdMethod(boolean b) { }
  }
  ```
- For static members, this is even the case if one of the classes inherits the other:

  ```
  class Echo {
      static void lastMethod(String s) { }
  }
  class Foxtrot extends Echo {
      // No overloading involved. Static members are never inherited,
      // so effectively, these two methods are unrelated
      static void lastMethod(boolean b) { }
  }
  ```

---

<sup>[More about override-equivalence](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.2)</sup>