# Get a parameter of a parametrized type in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, generics, member

So I have a class with a generic type

```
class GenericClass<T> {
// At some point in the class I have variable item of type T
val name: String = item.name
}
```

I know for sure that the type T of GenericClass will be used with a class that has the "name" property. But of course at the line I got a "Unresolved reference name". Android Studio generated me this code via "Create extension property T.name"

```
private val <T> T.name: String
    get() {}
```

I don't really know what to put in the bracket {} after the get. I tried `return name` but I got a recursive property error.

Any ideas ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you know that every type T has property `name` you can declare it implicitly:

```kotlin
// GenericClass.kt
class GenericClass<T : HasName> {
    // At some point in the class I have variable item of type T
    val name: String = item.name
}

// HasName.kt
// Create new interface with "name" property
interface HasName {
    val name: String
}
```

But also you must implement this new interface for all classes that can be used as T.

Comment: Mmmm.  The point here is that the method/property's name is irrelevant; Kotlin only treats them as the same if there's an inheritance relationship.  (In technical terms, Kotlin does not have [structural typing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Structural_type_system).)  So it doesn't matter if two `T`s both happen to have a property called `name` — unless they implement the same interface (or extend the same class), then they're unrelated methods that just happen to be spelled the same, and you can't call them the same way.  See also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17939305).

Comment: Isn't that what the HasName interface here is achieving @gidds?

Comment: @mattfreake Exactly!  That's why the code in the question doesn't work — and why this answer does.

Comment: Ahhh sorry I misunderstood you then :-) I thought you were criticising this answer.

Answer (score 0):

> I know for sure that the type T of GenericClass will be used with a class that has the "name" property.

Then you need to explicitly declare that. By default, `T` extends `Any?`. You need to narrow down possible types of `T` by declaring some interface, like

```kotlin
interface Named {
    val name : String
}
```

and passing `T : Named` as a generic paramteter. Also you need to make all classes, you're going to pass as a generic parameter, to implement that interface. By the way, `GenericClass<T : Named>` class itself could be declared as implementing that interface:

```kotlin
class GenericClass<T : Named> : Named {
    override val name: String = item.name
}
```